# Manager Returns Model Objects Once Per Request (Manager Drops Objects After Returning Them Once)

Tags: django, django-models

The behavior was unrelated to the problem as presented immediately below.  See the bottom of the post for an explanation.  thanks.

---

Hello,

I am currently experiencing the behavior that the default Manager for a particular Model returns the objects for this Model only once per request or per shell session.  Below is a PDB transcript from stopping in a view (but the behavior occurs without PDB, too):

```
#Nothing up my sleeves (using the default Manager):
(Pdb) p Entry.objects
<django.db.models.manager.Manager object at 0x18523b0>

#Now you see them...
(Pdb) Entry.objects.all()
[<Entry: Entry 1>, <Entry: Entry 2>, <Entry: Entry 3>, <Entry: Entry 4]

#Now you don't!
(Pdb) Entry.objects.all()
[]
```

Anytime I retrieve an object, that object no longer appears in later QuerySets.

```
#(New Request from above)

#If I only request one object then it is the one that disappears
(Pdb) Entry.objects.all()[0]
[<Entry: Entry 1>]

#Here Entry 1 is missing
(Pdb) Entry.objects.all()
[<Entry: Entry 2>, <Entry: Entry 3>, <Entry: Entry 4]

#And now they're all gone.
(Pdb) Entry.objects.all()
[]
```

This behavior is only for one of my models; the other models seems to query correctly.  I don't think that it has anything to do with my Model's definition, which is basicaly:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='entries')
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, related_name='entries')
    positive = models.BooleanField()
```

I apologize that my description is a little vague; I'm confused about how this behavior could arise and not sure where to poke around next.

The SQL generated by the Manager for the QuerySet is the same (and apparently correct) each time:

```
(Pdb) p Entry.objects.all().query.as_sql()
('SELECT "myapp_entry"."id", "myapp_entry"."user_id", "myapp_entry"."blog_id", "myapp_entry"."positive" FROM "myapp_entry"', ())
(Pdb) p Entry.objects.all()
[<Entry: Entry 1>, <Entry: Entry 2>, <Entry: Entry 3>, <Entry: Entry 4]

(Pdb) p Entry.objects.all().query.as_sql()
('SELECT "myapp_entry"."id", "myapp_entry"."user_id", "myapp_entry"."blog_id", "myapp_entry"."positive" FROM "myapp_entry"', ())
(Pdb) Entry.objects.all()
[]
```

I'm using Django 1.0.2, Python 2.6.1, and the SQLite that came packaged with Python 2.6.1 on a Mac OS 10.5 machine.

In response to one of the comments I tried renaming the `related_name` parameters to `entries1` and `entries2` to avoid a possible conflict but this did not change the behavior.

---

SOLVED (I think)

Sorry all, the problem was actually unrelated to the problem as I presented it.  I had a careless bug in one of my signals on Entry:

In `myapp.__init__`:

```
post_init.connect(entry_initialized, sender=Entry)
```

In `myapp.signals`:

```
def entry_initialized(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        #Disconnect signal to avoid infinite recursion
        post_init.disconnect(entry_initialized, sender=Entry)

        #Intializing a new Entry here would cause the recursion
        #Check to see if there is a previous entry by this user in this blog
        #In this app entries are unique by (User, Blog)
        #And what we want to do is remove the old Entry if the positive fields don't match
        prev_instance = Entry.objects.get(user=instance.user, blog=instance.blog)

        #This is an error: it is not appropriate to delete without some checking
        prev_instance.delete()

        post_init.connect(verification_initialized, sender=Verification)
    except:
        post_init.connect(verification_initialized, sender=Verification)
```

The correct version of my code would be:

```
        #Only delete if this is a different Entry with same user/blog and the positive field is different.
        if not instance.id == prev_instance and not instance.positive == prev_instance.positive:
            prev_instance.delete()
```

Comment: Yes, that's a head scratcher :)  Is the model manager the default?  If it's a custom manager you'll need to post the source to the manager somewhere.  Also, it might help to look at the query being generated, i.e., qs = Entry.objects.all() ; print qs.sql

Comment: Strange. Nothing wrong with the model. Even i would like to have a look at manager code if its not the default one. Please paste it.

Comment: maybe same related_name='entries' is affecting somehow, they should be defferent as far as i know

Comment: What version of Django are you using/do you have a custom manager/custom QuerySet for this model?

Comment: Are the objects actually deleted from the database? Or just from django's attempt to query them (ie: if you stop the django shell and restart it, do the objects show up again... at least for the first query :-) )?

Comment: I am very sorry, I think I have found the problem and it is something unrelated to the problem as I presented it.  Please see above.

Comment: If you solve your question. Put it in an answer and accept it. It's ok to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry all, the problem was actually unrelated to the problem as I presented it.  I had a careless bug in one of my signals on Entry:

In `myapp.__init__`:

```
post_init.connect(entry_initialized, sender=Entry)
```

In `myapp.signals`:

```
def entry_initialized(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        #Disconnect signal to avoid infinite recursion
        post_init.disconnect(entry_initialized, sender=Entry)

        #Intializing a new Entry here would cause the recursion
        #Check to see if there is a previous entry by this user in this blog
        #In this app entries are unique by (User, Blog)
        #And what we want to do is remove the old Entry if the positive fields don't match
        prev_instance = Entry.objects.get(user=instance.user, blog=instance.blog)

        #This is an error: it is not appropriate to delete without some checking
        prev_instance.delete()

        post_init.connect(verification_initialized, sender=Verification)
    except:
        post_init.connect(verification_initialized, sender=Verification)
```

The correct version of my code would be:

```
        #Only delete if this is a different Entry with same user/blog and the positive field is different.
        if not instance.id == prev_instance and not instance.positive == prev_instance.positive:
            prev_instance.delete()
```